# Meu codeigniter esta usando outra database ao invés da que eu selecionei

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho 2 projetos, um é a cópia do outro, um eu quero deixar online e o outro de teste pra eu programar em cima, logo eu copiei a database e copiei o projeto, mudei o nome, mudei diretorio, e coloquei os 2 no mesmo servidor, porém meu projeto de teste insiste em usar a antiga base de dados, por mais que no database.php esteja  a nova database.
Vou mandar o que está no database.php, essa corresponde a database do arquivo original:

```
$db['sas'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'MyServerIp',
'username' => 'sas',
'password' => '******',
'database' => 'sas',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => FALSE);
```

E este esta no database.php do projeto de test:

```
$db['sas'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'MyServerIp',
'username' => 'sastest',
'password' => '************',
'database' => 'sasClone',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => FALSE);
```

Nas aplicações eu chamo o banco da seguinte forma:

```
$dbsas = $this->load->database("sas", TRUE);
```

Espero ter sido claro, o meu projeto esta usando uma database diferente da que está no database.php.

Comment: Qual é o nome database que ele usa por vonta própria?

Comment: Não está sendo claro porque o nome das chaves são as mesmas... e por isso que não está pegando o banco corretamente

Comment: Sao sistemas diferentes, o nome da chave pode ser a mesma mas sao 2 database.php diferente, o sistema test que é a copia do primeiro, mesmo que no database.php referencia o sasClone, ele acaba usando o sas normal.

Answer (score 0):

Ja encontrei o problema, desculpa pessoal, foi um problema com o routes, aparentemente ele chama função do sistema normal ao invés do de test